# I can't get all of image attributes using Beautiful Soup and Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I really don't know how to get just src image from `data-image-large` when I call using `soup.select('img[data-image-large]')` I got this:

```
[<img alt="Adidas Originals NMD C2" class="img-responsive" data-image-large="https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fs3.store.hypebeast.com%2Fmedia%2Fimage%2Fbb%2Fc2%2FShoes_1_1-a1b3aed478ffec80ba8c68494053.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fit=max&amp;fm=pjpg&amp;h=1300&amp;ixlib=php-1.1.0&amp;q=90&amp;w=1000&amp;s=38d17241f278aa174c57ff8ba35b94da" data-index="0" data-zoom-image="https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fs3.store.hypebeast.com%2Fmedia%2Fimage%2Fbb%2Fc2%2FShoes_1_1-a1b3aed478ffec80ba8c68494053.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fm=pjpg&amp;ixlib=php-1.1.0&amp;q=90&amp;s=963ec1279be64e03f4ac2b7f7a9b36d4" itemprop="image" src="https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fs3.store.hypebeast.com%2Fmedia%2Fimage%2Fbb%2Fc2%2FShoes_1_1-a1b3aed478ffec80ba8c68494053.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fit=max&amp;fm=pjpg&amp;h=832&amp;ixlib=php-1.1.0&amp;q=90&amp;w=640&amp;s=92dea597a56bcf9d38f1f9a5f4d3c590" srcset="https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fs3.store.hypebeast.com%2Fmedia%2Fimage%2Fbb%2Fc2%2FShoes_1_1-a1b3aed478ffec80ba8c68494053.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fit=max&amp;fm=pjpg&amp;h=1300&amp;ixlib=php-1.1.0&amp;q=90&amp;w=1000&amp;s=38d17241f278aa174c57ff8ba35b94da 2x"/>, <img alt="Adidas Originals NMD C2" class="img-responsive" data-image-large="https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fs3.store.hypebeast.com%2Fmedia%2Fimage%2F4e%2F44%2FShoes_1_2-11c2134891612312561d9d8e93f5.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fit=max&amp;fm=pjpg&amp;h=1300&amp;ixlib=php-1.1.0&amp;q=90&amp;w=1000&amp;s=27df63d14cf5183ccc3d825f6994a232" data-index="1" data-zoom-image="https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fs3.store.hypebeast.com%2Fmedia%2Fimage%2F4e%2F44%2FShoes_1_2-11c2134891612312561d9d8e93f5.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fm=pjpg&amp;ixlib=php-1.1.0&amp;q=90&amp;s=20dbba1f381441b6cf1654b8bb03a194" src="https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fs3.store.hypebeast.com%2Fmedia%2Fimage%2F4e%2F44%2FShoes_1_2-11c2134891612312561d9d8e93f5.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fit=max&amp;fm=pjpg&amp;h=832&amp;ixlib=php-1.1.0&amp;q=90&amp;w=640&amp;s=4fb51fcf7948eeb5622fb63c25d6944f" srcset="https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fs3.store.hypebeast.com%2Fmedia%2Fimage%2F4e%2F44%2FShoes_1_2-11c2134891612312561d9d8e93f5.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fit=max&amp;fm=pjpg&amp;h=1300&amp;ixlib=php-1.1.0&amp;q=90&amp;w=1000&amp;s=27df63d14cf5183ccc3d825f6994a232 2x"/>, <img alt="Adidas Originals NMD C2" class="img-responsive" data-image-large="https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fs3.store.hypebeast.com%2Fmedia%2Fimage%2Fa6%2Ff4%2FShoes_1_3-f30adb388e477e7fd0a7bc2d172a.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fit=max&amp;fm=pjpg&amp;h=1300&amp;ixlib=php-1.1.0&amp;q=90&amp;w=1000&amp;s=505e637d9b5a82bcf0d84a9d335e080c" data-index="2" data-zoom-image="https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fs3.store.hypebeast.com%2Fmedia%2Fimage%2Fa6%2Ff4%2FShoes_1_3-f30adb388e477e7fd0a7bc2d172a.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fm=pjpg&amp;ixlib=php-1.1.0&amp;q=90&amp;s=fb0019b2304ab3f970a03f8ec7faf7fb" src="https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fs3.store.hypebeast.com%2Fmedia%2Fimage%2Fa6%2Ff4%2FShoes_1_3-f30adb388e477e7fd0a7bc2d172a.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fit=max&amp;fm=pjpg&amp;h=832&amp;ixlib=php-1.1.0&amp;q=90&amp;w=640&amp;s=44ac890d49273e9d382f41e97ec70f3d" srcset="https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fs3.store.hypebeast.com%2Fmedia%2Fimage%2Fa6%2Ff4%2FShoes_1_3-f30adb388e477e7fd0a7bc2d172a.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fit=max&amp;fm=pjpg&amp;h=1300&amp;ixlib=php-1.1.0&amp;q=90&amp;w=1000&amp;s=505e637d9b5a82bcf0d84a9d335e080c 2x"/>, <img alt="Adidas Originals NMD C2" class="img-responsive" data-image-large="https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fs3.store.hypebeast.com%2Fmedia%2Fimage%2Fef%2F15%2FShoes_1_4-711b1e1627aaeb93e4b60395cc4a.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fit=max&amp;fm=pjpg&amp;h=1300&amp;ixlib=php-1.1.0&amp;q=90&amp;w=1000&amp;s=335ad8e02f38cf1315fd8d77bb25e773" data-index="3" data-zoom-image="https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fs3.store.hypebeast.com%2Fmedia%2Fimage%2Fef%2F15%2FShoes_1_4-711b1e1627aaeb93e4b60395cc4a.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fm=pjpg&amp;ixlib=php-1.1.0&amp;q=90&amp;s=a1a5b31af43c8ea5e125243dcebc9674" src="https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fs3.store.hypebeast.com%2Fmedia%2Fimage%2Fef%2F15%2FShoes_1_4-711b1e1627aaeb93e4b60395cc4a.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fit=max&amp;fm=pjpg&amp;h=832&amp;ixlib=php-1.1.0&amp;q=90&amp;w=640&amp;s=ef9389f17a6557b4932a55312eda61a1" srcset="https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fs3.store.hypebeast.com%2Fmedia%2Fimage%2Fef%2F15%2FShoes_1_4-711b1e1627aaeb93e4b60395cc4a.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fit=max&amp;fm=pjpg&amp;h=1300&amp;ixlib=php-1.1.0&amp;q=90&amp;w=1000&amp;s=335ad8e02f38cf1315fd8d77bb25e773 2x"/>]
```

I know how to get 1 by 1 using xpath and make this command: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gallery"]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/img` but, I also don't know how to get all of them using selenium.

My script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

#url target
driver.get("https://hbx.com/categories/sneakers")

#masuk
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="products-container"]/div[1]').click()
url = driver.current_url
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).html, "html.parser")
soup.select('img[data-image-large]')

#color
def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="product-form"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/select').text
except: NoSuchElementException

#size
def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="product-form"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]').text
    except: NoSuchElementException

#back
driver.back()
```

What I want is just to get all of `data-image-large` image source from here https://hbx.com/brands/adidas-originals/nmd-c2

Comment: Why do you make `requests.get(url)` if you can scrape all required data from page opened in browser instance directly?

Comment: Please post separate questions as actual separate questions.  There's no harm in that and as it is you just post well, one question per question.

Comment: @Andersson I thought just open with selenium not detecting as human. So it is ok without it?

Comment: @Iguananaut my bad, I'll make separate post then!

Comment: @Filmar, I have no idea what does it means *"not detecting as human"*, but yes, you can avoid using `requests` and `bs4` :) What exactly you want to do? What is desired output? your goal is not quite clear

Comment: @Andersson Owh I see. Because before i failed get all of `data-image-large` using selenium so I try using bs4. Sorry, what I want is just to get all of `data-image-large` image source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to scrape all image sources, you can try below code:

```
driver.get(https://hbx.com/brands/adidas-originals/nmd-c2)
pictures = [picture.get_attribute('data-image-large') for picture in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div#gallery li>img.img-responsive')]

print(pictures)
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm not quite clear about what I want before. I'll edit again my post.  After I make this command `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="products-container"]/div[1]').click()` so my browser going here: `https://hbx.com/brands/adidas-originals/nmd-c2`

Comment: Yep. That's right. I do the same but without clicking on each image, but open it one by one with `get()`

Comment: Thank's for trying! Really appreaciate that! I'll wait maybe someone can get all of them. For temporary just get them one by one.

Comment: *get all of them*? get all of what? Do you want to get all images from one single page or one image for each page or all images for all pages?

Comment: I mean get all images from `data-image-large` just one single page.

Comment: OMG :) `pictures = [picture.get_attribute('data-image-large') for picture in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div#gallery li>img.img-responsive')]`

Comment: Woah, thank's man! You're cool! I just know about **selenium get images**. I learn a lot from this. Have a nice day!